# BLEU score from Microsoft Translator Hub is 0.00

Tags: microsoft-translator

I just started exploring Microsoft Translator Hub and my question is if i use dictionary to preserve word from being translated from english to korean, then steps for it will be :

1. Inside my excel, for the first row i will add the language code
2. For the second row, it will be the value to preserve. For example: Under 'en' column, i will put 'BACK' as the value and under 'ko' column, i will also put 'BACK' as the value.
3. Upload it as a document.
4. Uncheck all the other document under training tab, check the document just uploaded under dictionary tab.
5. Start training the document.

So, ive done all of this steps but the BLEU score still comes out 0.00. Am i doing it wrong? Did i understand the use of Translator Hub wrongly also?

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Just want to add another info, after finish training the document, inside the evaluate result tab, it doesnt show anything. It just show the 2 language that is used. Which in this case, english and korean and under it, nothing. Is it supposed to be showing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a dictionary-only training in the Microsoft Translator Hub does not produce a BLEU score. This is expected. You didn't upload any training, tuning or test set for this type of training. Refer to the [Translator Hub User Guide](https://hub.microsofttranslator.com/Help/Download/Microsoft%20Translator%20Hub%20User%20Guide.pdf) section 2.6. Dictionary-only training.

To answer your second question, if the training is successful, the 'Evaluate Results' tab shows the machine translation of sentences that were a part of the test dataset. Refer to the Hub User Guide, section 3.3.5. Evaluate Results. 
As there was no test set uploaded, the tab shows nothing. This is expected.

Comment: Hi. Tqvm for the clarification. Just want to ask a few more question. 
1. If i have deployed 1 trained system, and i would like to add few more vocab into my dictionary, will there be any downtime in the translation service? Will i still be able to use the previous dictionary in my translation api service? 
2. Is it possible to use translation hub service outside of https://hub.microsofttranslator.com? What i mean is that i create another webpage which user can upload excel file, train and deploy the service (All of it outside the microsofttranslator page - Using Api service)

Comment: Do tell if you would like me to pass this question into another question page. Tqvm.

Comment: The Hub exposes an API. You can implement the functions of the Hub using the Hub API: https://hub.microsofttranslator.com/swagger.

Comment: @ChrisWendt Thanks for the reply. Will look into it. Regarding the other question. Do you have any idea? What i mean by downtime is that during redeploying my updated dictionary system (containing new vocab), will the previous dictionary which i have deployed can still be use in translation api service (Calling translation api service with category id)? Or is it that i just need to wait for another 2 days so that the category id will be added with the new vocab ? Thanks again.

Comment: The previously deployed system will stay alive and up until the new system finishes deployment. No downtime.

Comment: @ChrisWendt Tqvm again for the clarification.

Comment: @ChrisWendt Hi again. Really sorry to disturb. Just got another question when im exploring Hub Translator Api ( The Swagger link that you have provided ). Hope you dont mind answering it. Tqvm. Here`s the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941892/how-to-use-hubupload-post-api